# Token Provider Asp.Net WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, token

na empresa que trabalho fazemos autenticação e autorização via Bearer Token em uma app asp.net webapi, porém guardo algumas informações sobre permissões de usuário com Claims... e isso faz com que o Token fique gigantesco.

Encontrei uma forma de gerar o token eu mesmo, pra montar um hash próprio estendendo esta classe **AuthenticationTokenProvider**.

```
public class AccessTokenProvider: AuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    public override void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        var token = Guid.NewGuid();
        context.SetToken(token.ToString());
    }
}
```

Mas na hora da requisição esse token gerado por min não funciona, a impressão que tenho é que ele não identifica o usuário por este token...

Tem mais algum método que preciso sobrescrever ?

De qualquer forma o meu objetivo é apenas deixar meu token menor, se houver outra forma de fazer isso também ajuda.

Abraço!

---

Após algumas pesquisas implementei dessa forma:

```
public class AccessTokenProvider: AuthenticationTokenProvider
{

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket> _authenticationCodes =
                  new ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket>(StringComparer.Ordinal);

    public override Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            context.SetToken(token);

            _authenticationCodes.TryAdd(token, context.Ticket);
        });
    }

    public override Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            AuthenticationTicket ticket;

            if (_authenticationCodes.TryGetValue(context.Token, out ticket))
            {
                if (ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc != null && ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.Value < DateTime.UtcNow)
                {
                    _authenticationCodes.TryRemove(context.Token, out ticket);
                }
                context.SetTicket(ticket);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

mas o método **ReceiveAsync** nunca é chamado.

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo a minha própria dúvida:

`BearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider(), 
                AccessTokenProvider = Options.AccessTokenProvider // -- Esta linha resolveu
            };`

Faltava informar que o gerador de token havia sido cutomizado nas opções do BearerAuthenticationOptions.

só isso

Comment: Você realmente precisa criar o seu próprio token? Aconselho procurar soluções como OAuth, pois são praticas conhecidas do mercado.

Comment: Pra ser sincero não é uma necessidade extrema, mas como mostrei na minha resposta, consegui fazer.. Obrigado pelo comentário